there are verses that god says kill amolek babies, which I get, ewww amoleks but eat your own children? Is this real?
Deuteronomy 28:53-63
53 "You will eat your children, the flesh of your sons and daughters the Lord your God has given you during the siege and hardship your enemy imposes on you.
54 The most sensitive and refined man among you will look grudgingly at his brother, the wife he embraces, and the rest of his children,
55 refusing to share with any of them his children's flesh that he will eat because he has nothing left during the siege and hardship your enemy imposes on you in all your towns.
56 The most sensitive and refined woman among you, who would not venture to set the sole of her foot on the ground because of her refinement and sensitivity, will begrudge the husband she embraces, her son, and her daughter,

I think I may have missed the point of the question. Could you restate it, in clearer terms, please ? (The quoted reference is quite clear : God is warning that inevitable judgment is about to fall, unless there is repentance.)

Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below). Please also see the archive of 15,000 question/answer contributions as to how these policies play out in practice. Moderators are elected by the community of users to oversee the integrity of the site.

Welcome to the group. If you intend to stay with us, please do take the Tour. It's important to phrase your question seriously. ("ewww amaleks" doesn't measure up) Also it would help if you mention the verse (1 Samuel 15:3) that speaks of killing Amalekite children.

The OP confuses a command (to kill the Amalekites) with a prediction (that certain of the Israelites will commit cannibalism). The latter is not done at God's instruction but prophesies what will happen if the Israelites do not heed God's voice. (28:15)
The command to kill the Amalekites is justified on the grounds that the Amalekites opposed the Israelites during the Exodus:

2 Thus says the Lord of hosts, ‘I have noted what Amalek did to Israel
in opposing them on the way when they came up out of Egypt. 3 Now go
and strike Amalek and devote to destruction all that they have. Do not
spare them, but kill both man and woman, child and infant, ox and
sheep, camel and donkey.’”

The prediction of cannibalism is given in the context of two if-then prophecies. It is not an instruction but a warning. The first if-then proposition is a prediction of blessing:

If you faithfully obey the voice of the Lord your God, being careful
to do all his commandments that I command you today, the Lord your God
will set you high above all the nations of the earth. 2 And all these
blessings shall come upon you and overtake you, if you obey the voice
of the Lord your God. (Dt. 28:1-2)

The second if-then proposition is a prediction that God's people will be overtaken by a curse for disobedience:

If you will not obey the voice of the Lord your God or be careful to
do all his commandments and his statutes that I command you today,
then all these curses shall come upon you and overtake you. (Dt.
28:15)

Conclusion: The OP rightly identifies two problematic verses - one a commandment to carry out the complete slaughter of an ethnic group, including women and children; the other predicting that the Israelites will engage in cannibalism against their own children. While both present serious moral questions, the second is less problematic than the first, because the Lord did not command it.

I agree with this answer.  It could be improved by citing an instance where the latter prophecy of cannibalism was fulfilled such as 2 Kings 6.

The question and the answer both miss the point that God instituted a covenant in the earth, an agreement with one particular nation to set forth the everlasting testament on earth before all peoples. Any nation that withstood God's purpose (a purpose that was eternal and was for the salvation of an innumerable multitude from destruction) that nation was to be wiped out, removed out of the way. This is righteous. This is the love of God.
